# Как установить обработчик события на клавишу Enter?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно установить обработчик события на клавишу Enter. То есть чтобы при нажатии клавиши запускалась функция (код клавиши - 13). Ниже код, который скорее всего с ошибками:

```
keyCode==13.addEventListener("KeyDown", нажатие, false);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
        function addEvent(obj, type, fn){
            if (obj.addEventListener){
                obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
            } else if(obj.attachEvent) {
                obj.attachEvent( "on"+type, fn );
            } else {
                obj["on"+type] = fn;
            }
        }
        addEvent(document, 'keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                alert('You pressed Enter');
            }
        });
```